# what packages are needed to use perl with cygwin

Tags: installation, emulator

i want to know what packages are needed so that Perl can work under windows environment, i need this, because some scripts or shell commands are with the UNIX structure and i don't want to be changing the code.
does somebody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can correct me if Im wrong, but I believe all you need is the Perl package under Interpreters.  If there are dependencies, it will install them automatically.

Comment: ah ok thanks i thought it would be necessary to install other packages.

Comment: yes it was not necessary, just marked perl and that's it

Comment: if this was the answer you needed, be sure to mark it as the answer for future visitors